# building a php array that will make specific JSON

Tags: php, json

I need to generate the following JSON:

```
{
"title": "my form",
"fields": [
{
  "type": "short_text",
  "question": "What is your name?"
},
{
  "type": "multiple_choice",
  "question": "How often do you want to receive emails?",
  "choices": [
    {
      "label": "Daily"
    },
    {
      "label": "Weekly"
    },
    {
      "label": "Monthly"
    },]
},]
```

I'm trying to do it with this php code:

```
$data = array(
   "title" => "my form",
   "fields" => array ( 
                  array (
                      "type" => "short_text",
                      "question" => "What is your name?"
                  ),
                  array ( 
                        array (
                              "type" => "multiple_choice",
                              "question" => "How often do you want to receive emails?", 
                              "choices" => (
                                   array ("label" => "Daily")
                              ), 
                              (array ("label" =>   "Weekly")), 
                              (array ("label" => "Monthly"))
                        )
                   )
               )
);
$output = json_encode($data);
```

...but it's not working.

I'd appreciate any help you guys can offer!

Comment: if you would have formatted your code properly, you would have seen the mistakes you've made: in fields-array you stack too many arrays bf 'multiple choices', then in 'choices' you have a syntax error ( `(` when expecting `array(` )

Comment: I formatted the code. Just as information for anybody else reading this and wondering why I complained about not formatted code... ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$data = array (
  'title' => 'my form',
  'fields' => 
  array (
    array (
      'type' => 'short_text',
      'question' => 'What is your name?',
    ),
    array (
      'type' => 'multiple_choice',
      'question' => 'How often do you want to receive emails?',
      'choices' => 
      array (
        array (
          'label' => 'Daily',
        ),
        array (
          'label' => 'Weekly',
        ),
        array (
          'label' => 'Monthly',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
$output = json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly -- much obliged for the help!